# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP with SSL3?

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, vbscript, windows-server-2008, msxml

Using VBScript, want to talk to a HTTPS website but it fails with:

> The client and server cannot
>   communicate, because they do not
>   possess a common algorithm

Found out this is because it needs to use SSL3. How can I tell it to use SSL v3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ServerXmlHTTP relies on [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which supports SSLv3. See the `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_SSL3` in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384066%28VS.85%29.aspx). What version of MSXML are you using? You may want to try using one of the later versions. See the documentation on [ProgID information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757837%28VS.85%29.aspx).